# Running Selenium Chrome Driver in Airflow

Tags: selenium-webdriver, airflow

I have a py file that runs a selenium driver to capture LinkedIn job data. It runs fine locally, but when I try to run the file in an Airflow DAG I get an error.

I am running Airflow downloaded locally in a Conda env.

Here is the error:

```
Broken DAG: [/home/christopher/airflow/dags/jobs/Jobs_Airflow.py] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/christopher/anaconda3/envs/airflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 440, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/christopher/anaconda3/envs/airflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable
  (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.122)
Stacktrace:
#0 0x558b3105cd29 <unknown>
```

Does anyone know what the error might be? I can't find anything addressing this issue directly. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

I tried moving the Chrome driver into the DAG folder in case Airflow could only access files within there, but that did not solve the issue